# How to transfer data from a TextBox into a formula in another TextBox

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I am learning this programming for the past few days and I am having difficulty in transferring data from a TextBox and put that value into a formula in another TextBox.Here's an example:

```
    Private Sub TextBox7_Change()
        i = TextBox7
        ii = i / 100
    End Sub
```

And I need to substitute the value in ii into..

```
    Private Sub TextBox12_Change()

        TextBox12 = (d * 1000) / (e * 1000 * c * ff * ii)

    End Sub
```

Comment: try `TextBox12.Text = (d * 1000) / (e * 1000 * c * ff * CDbl(TextBox7.Text) / 100)` or if `The TextBox7 is in the CheckBox environment.` try `TextBox12.Text = (d * 1000) / (e * 1000 * c * ff * CDbl(TextBox7.Value) / 100)`

Answer (score 0):

change  `TextBox7_Change()` event as follows to convert it's text value into an integer.

```
Private Sub TextBox7_Change()
  i = Integer.Parse(TextBox7.Text)
  ii = i / 100
End Sub
```

Comment: I am using Macro Excel with the VBA codings for the project. Do you have any idea on solving the same situation in Macro Excel?

Comment: I have no experience in Macro Excel, but according to the snippets you have given above, you have to change the type of TextBox7s' value into an integer. Did you try it?

Comment: maybe it's something specific to  VBA and Macro Excel. Please add those two as tags and one with expertise in VBA and Macro Excel will get to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Public Class FIND_WINDOW_AND_BUTTON

```
'-----------GLOBAL VARIABLE--------------

Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim ii As Integer = 0
Dim d As Double = 5.2
Dim A As Double = 3.1
Dim c As Double = 1.2
Dim ff As Double = 9.6

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    i = TextBox1.Text
    ii = i / 100

    TextBox2.Text = (d * 1000) / (A * 1000 * c * ff * ii)
End Sub
```

End Class

Do you mean like this ? you can transfer the data in one event without calling another.

Comment: The TextBox7 is in the CheckBox environment. So, I need to call the value whenever the CheckBox is enabled. Also, the value for i is efficiency of a solar PV module.